# Gearman installation in windows

Tags: windows, makefile, installation, gearman, libevent

i've been working on this for days, and I really don't have any clue to what's going on

I'm trying to install gearman on windows and followed EXACTLY what's on this link:

http://www.phpvs.net/2010/11/30/installing-gearman-and-gearmand-on-windows-with-cygwin/

However, no luck. I've installed libevent and i'm on installation of gearman:

I've only managed to execute **./configure** on cygwin.
After that, using **make** :

```
make -j2  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/gearman'
  CXX      libgearman/libgearman_libgearman_la-error.lo
libgearman/error.cc: In function 'gearman_return_t gearman_universal_set_perror(gearman_universal_st&, gearman_return_t, int, const char*, const char*, const char*, ...)':
libgearman/error.cc:218:83: error: 'strerror_r' was not declared in this scope
     errmsg_ptr= strerror_r(universal._error.system_error(), errmsg, sizeof(errmsg));
                                                                                   ^
Makefile:6247: recipe for target 'libgearman/libgearman_libgearman_la-error.lo' failed
make[1]: *** [libgearman/libgearman_libgearman_la-error.lo] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/gearman'
Makefile:3050: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This comes on, and I don't know what I've done wrong. I need help on this. Thanks!